# Trigonometric identities involved $\sin(\alpha)$, $\cos(\alpha)$, $\tan(\alpha)$

Tags: trigonometry

$\alpha$ is valid between  $-90<\alpha<90$ Degrees

Show that,

$$ \frac{\tan^6(\alpha)-\tan^4(\alpha)+2}{\tan^6(\alpha)-2\tan^2(\alpha)+4 }\cdot\cos^2(\alpha) =
  \frac{\sin^6(\alpha)+\sin^4(\alpha)-2}{\sin^6(\alpha)-2\sin^2(\alpha)-4 } $$

---

$$
  \frac{\sin^6(\alpha)+\sin^4(\alpha)-2}{\sin^6(\alpha)-2\sin^2(\alpha)-4 } =\frac{(\sin^2(\alpha)-1)(\sin^4(\alpha)+2\sin(\alpha)+2)} {(\sin^2(\alpha)-4)(\sin^4(\alpha)+2\sin(\alpha)+2)} $$

$$
  \frac{\sin^6(\alpha)+\sin^4(\alpha)-2}{\sin^6(\alpha)-2\sin^2(\alpha)-4 } =\frac{\sin^2(\alpha)-1} {\sin^2(\alpha)-4} $$

Can this expression be simplify more further?
$$ \frac{\tan^6(\alpha)-\tan^4(\alpha)+2}{\tan^6(\alpha)-2\tan^2(\alpha)+4 }\cdot\cos^2(\alpha)$$

**please give a hand here can't seem to do it**

Comment: It is always a good idea to start by changing the tangent and cotangents into sine and cosines.Pythagorean identities can help too.

Comment: numerators and denominators can be factorized

Comment: How? I can't see it please show me.

Comment: @pisquare e.g. : $
x^{\,6}  + x^{\,4}  - 2 = \left( {x - 1} \right)\left( {x + 1} \right)\left( {2x^{\,2}  + x^{\,4}  + 2} \right)
$ and similarly for the other three terms, and the fractions gets much simplified.

Comment: @G Cab thank, $1+1-2=0$, then used division of polynomial. As for the other I can't see any values to make the equation zero! If you do show me another example, but I doubt it.

Comment: $ x^6-2x^2-4=(x^2-2)(x^4+2x^2+2)$' I was wrong.

Comment: Can't find a clever way...but if you let $\tan(\alpha/2)=x$, you'll have $\sin(\alpha)=2x/(x^2+1)$, $\cos(\alpha)=(1-x^2)/(1+x^2)$, $\tan(\alpha)=(2x)/(1-x^2)$ then the rest of the problem is just simplification(quite painful though...).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

Answer (score 1):

So, for the LH fraction:
$$
{{x^{\,6}  - x^{\,4}  + 2} \over {x^{\,6}  - 2x^{\,2}  + 4}} = {{y^{\,3}  - y^{\,2}  + 2} \over {y^{\,3}  - 2y + 4}}
$$
then by Ruffini's method
$$
 = {{\left( {y + 1} \right)\left( {y^{\,2}  - 2y^{\,2}  + 1} \right)} \over {\left( {y + 2} \right)\left( {y^{\,2}  - 2y^{\,2}  + 1} \right)}} = {{x^{\,2}  + 1} \over {x^{\,2}  + 2}}
$$
Same method for the RH fraction, as already done, but **corrected** to$$
{{\sin ^{\,2} \alpha  - 1} \over {\sin ^{\,2} \alpha  - 2}}
$$